# New paypal system has stopped working with my code

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I've not been able to work on a project of mine for about 1 month.  Now that I have some time to get back into it.  I have noticed that paypal have done some changes.

Before my temporary break from this project, I was able to send off payments using the paypal api's.  But now, when I use the same code, I get the following message:

> Preapproval API call failed. Detailed Error Message: The receiver is
>   based in a country that isn't enabled to receive paymentsError Code:
>   580022Error Severity: ErrorError Domain: PLATFORMError Category:
>   Application

I'm in the UK and my paypalplaform.php file hasn't changed at all.  The only thing I have changed is the api credential stuff with the new credentials I have been given:

```
$PROXY_HOST = '127.0.0.1';
$PROXY_PORT = '808';

$Env = "sandbox";

$API_UserName = "new-facilitator_api-email-goes-here";
$API_Password = "password-goes-here";
$API_Signature = "sig-goes-here";
// AppID is preset for sandbox use
//   If your application goes live, you will be assigned a value for the live environment by PayPal as part of the live onboarding process
$API_AppID = "APP-80W284485P519543T";
$API_Endpoint = "";

if ($Env == "sandbox") 
{
        $API_Endpoint = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments";
}
else
{
        $API_Endpoint = "https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments";
}
```

Why is this no longer working?  I am not getting any error in the apache error.log file.

Comment: Find it really annoying that I have to wait 2 whole days to setup a bounty to attract more attention to the question...

Comment: In the old paypal sandbox system, there was a general api username, password, signature for the sandbox account, which is what i used in the paypalplatform.php file.  I can't seem to find a general api username, password, signature in the new sandbox paypal system, which is why I tried using the facilitator paypal sandbox test account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies with the Sandbox AppID you're using: APP-80W284485P519543T.

We're aware of this issue and are working to resolve it. I'll let you know as soon as this is fixed.
In the meantime you should be able to resume testing with US accounts.

Comment: This should be resolved now. Let me know if you see any further issues.

Comment: I am using the iOS MPL library version 2.1.1 But I am still getting an error 520002 (Internal Error) while doing an adaptive payment if either sender or receiver is outside US. Can you please help?

Comment: Hey, PayPal::SDK::AdaptivePayments.new not working for feesPayer as "PRIMARYRECEIVER" but working for "SENDER". I have a india based sandbox account. Is issue has not resolved yet?

Answer (score 2):

I finally got a response from PayPal which looks promising:

> Response Via Email (xxxx)
>   Dear xxxxx,
>   my name is xxxxx from Merchant Technical Services
>   This is a known issue that I am working with our engineers closely on,
>   I apologize for the inconvenience this has caused.
>
> Sincerely,
>   xxxxxx
>   Merchant Technical Support
>   PayPal, an eBay
>   Company

Comment: This should be resolved now. Let me know if you see any further issues.

Comment: I am now receiving a different error:

559044 - The receiver buy2uk@ff.com does not accept payments in this Currency.

The payment was made in GBP by a UK account and the receiver has a UK account.