# 580022 - The receiver is based in a country that isn't enabled to receive payments

Tags: paypal, chained

I'm making a crowdfunding website using PHP and I'm using preapproval and chained payment.

I’m able to create and cancel pre-approved payments programmatically just fine, however when I try to pay one of them, I get the error:

580022 - The receiver is based in a country that isn't enabled to receive payments

I have two receivers, the primary receiver gets 95% of the amount and is the owner of the project which is being pledged.
The remaining 5% goes to me as a commission.

Both receivers have UK PayPal accounts and I’m working in sandbox.

Any idea what’s wrong? I hope this functionality is available in the UK else I’ve come all this way for nothing!

I am using this API to make the payments: https://github.com/angelleye/paypal/

Here is the generated XML which is being sent to paypal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PayRequest xmlns="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap">
  <requestEnvelope xmlns="">
    <detailLevel>ReturnAll</detailLevel>
    <errorLanguage>en_US</errorLanguage>
  </requestEnvelope>
  <actionType xmlns="">PAY_PRIMARY</actionType>
  <cancelUrl xmlns="">http://89.238.152.7/funding/error/cancelled</cancelUrl>
  <clientDetails xmlns="">
    <applicationId xmlns="">APP-80W284485P519543T</applicationId>
    <customerId xmlns="">1</customerId>
    <ipAddress xmlns="">92.27.172.254</ipAddress>
    <partnerName xmlns="">The Funding Forum</partnerName>
  </clientDetails>
  <currencyCode xmlns="">GBP</currencyCode>
  <feesPayer xmlns="">EACHRECEIVER</feesPayer>
  <fundingConstraint xmlns="">
    <allowedFundingType xmlns="">
      <fundingTypeInfo xmlns="">
        <fundingType xmlns="">ECHECK</fundingType>
      </fundingTypeInfo>
      <fundingTypeInfo xmlns="">
        <fundingType xmlns="">BALANCE</fundingType>
      </fundingTypeInfo>
      <fundingTypeInfo xmlns="">
        <fundingType xmlns="">CREDITCARD</fundingType>
      </fundingTypeInfo>
    </allowedFundingType>
  </fundingConstraint>
  <ipnNotificationUrl xmlns="">http://89.238.152.7/paypal/ipn.php</ipnNotificationUrl>
  <preapprovalKey xmlns="">PA-8EE05998ST379664R</preapprovalKey>
  <receiverList xmlns="">
    <receiver xmlns="">
      <amount xmlns="">0.5</amount>
      <email xmlns="">james_1351605562_per@design365.co.uk</email>
      <paymentType xmlns="">GOODS</paymentType>
      <primary xmlns="">true</primary>
    </receiver>
    <receiver xmlns="">
      <amount xmlns="">0.02</amount>
      <email xmlns="">james_1351605505_biz@design365.co.uk</email>
      <paymentType xmlns="">GOODS</paymentType>
      <primary xmlns="">false</primary>
    </receiver>
  </receiverList>
  <sender>
    <useCredentials xmlns="">
  </useCredentials>
</sender>
  <account xmlns="">
    <email xmlns="">poeljames@gmail.com</email>
    <phone xmlns="">
  </phone>
</account>
  <returnUrl xmlns="">http://89.238.152.7/funding/success/return</returnUrl>
</PayRequest>
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Comment: It seems to go through fine when I use US sandbox accounts :/ Why wouldn't this work with UK??

Comment: possible duplicate of [New paypal system has stopped working with my code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552292/new-paypal-system-has-stopped-working-with-my-code)

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer in [New paypal system has stopped working with my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552292/new-paypal-system-has-stopped-working-with-my-code/15625919#15625919)
The problem lies with the AppID in Sandbox. We're working to resolve this as we speak.

edit: This should be resolved now. Let me know if you see any further issues.

Comment: Thanks, Robert. Hope this gets sorted soon, can you keep me updated?
For now I will use US sandbox accounts but would like to test UK ones before launch.

Comment: This should be resolved now. Let me know if you see any further issues.

Comment: I am now receiving a different error:

559044 - The receiver buy2uk@ff.com does not accept payments in this Currency.

The payment was made in GBP by a UK account and the receiver has a UK account.