# Paypal Mobile Payment Libraries return error code 580022 on login

Tags: android, ios, paypal, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I'm stuck in a problem when logging in to paypal. I'm using Mobile Payment Libraries (MPL) package for Android, Titanium Paypal module for iOS and also for native iOS. When I integrate into iPhone, initial configuration are below:

```
[PayPal initializeWithAppID:@"APP-8SE84722YD658401M" forEnvironment:ENV_LIVE];
[PayPal getPayPalInst].feePayer = FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER;
PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
payment.paymentType = TYPE_SERVICE;
payment.recipient = self.payPalSettings.recipient;
payment.paymentCurrency = self.payPalSettings.currency;
payment.memo = self.payPalSettings.memo;
payment.merchantName = self.payPalSettings.merchantName;
payment.ipnUrl = self.payPalSettings.ipnURL;
```

Where, payPalSettings is to store the parameters for LIVE mode. But after calling:

```
[[PayPal getPayPalInst] checkoutWithPayment:payment];
```

then signing in to Paypal, there is an error:

```
Error code:580022
message: Invalid Phone Format 1 Account not found. Invalid phone number format.
```

With the same configuration, in Android, the error is:

```
An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: Presumably you tried to log in to PayPal by typing a phone number and PIN? Exactly what did you type for phone number? (Feel to change some digits to other digits here on this public forum, but do NOT change any punctuation or other formatting. And if your entry included a country code, please do not change that.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've used email/password to log in to Paypal. I've already succeed on Sandbox environment. But it's failed on LIVE environment. Any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552292/new-paypal-system-has-stopped-working-with-my-code/15625919#15625919

Comment: Thank the1pawan! But it's related to Sandbox environment in PHP. Do you have another idea?